# how to set a div to 100% width within a parent div that has 40px padding

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I may have asked this question in a confusing way.

Basically I need this: http://www.jayflood.com/layout.jpg

I'm sure there are a ton of ways to do this, but my problem lies in working within a preexisting structure. The parent container does not have a set width, but does have 40px of padding.

I need the content div to be considered width 100% so I can properly divide up the divs within.

The question is basically - Is it possible to have a smaller containing div have a 100% width.

Comment: The image you link to is broken. Also it will help us if you could post the html and css. It helps even more if you post it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: just fixed it @HelloWorld

Comment: OK so you want the content div to cover the padding of the parent container and be 100% of screen width? Why not just set the parent's padding to 0, then set the content div to 100%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set its margin to -40px

```
div {
   margin:-40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

subtract the padding using a negative margin so if the parent has 40px padding then set the child to have -40px margin ex.

```
#parent{
  padding: 40px;
}
```

and

```
#child{
  width: 100%;
  margin: -40px;
}
```